# Cypress API Call Forbidden 403 Error ( "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN, DENY" )

Tags: api, cross-domain, ui-automation, cypress

**Issue :**

- I successfully Login and make a Post Call and receive for following
  error after making a cy.request( )POST API call :
- I was able to make cy.request( ) get API calls which retured 200 , so API call error seems specific to the above cy.request( ) POST API call

**Error:**

The response we got was:

Status: 403 - Forbidden
Headers: {
  "date": "Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:10:19 GMT",
  "server": "Apache",
  "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN, DENY",

**Full Error**

CypressError: cy.request() failed on:

https://uat1.dns2.merchantportal.eu/MerchantApiWeb/rest/secure/user/financial/preauthorisation

The response we received from your web server was:

> 403: Forbidden

This was considered a failure because the status code was not '2xx' or '3xx'.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: 'failOnStatusCode: false'

---

**The request we sent was:**

Method: POST
URL: https://uat1.dns2.merchantportal.eu/MerchantApiWeb/rest/secure/user/financial/preauthorisation
Headers: {
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "Cookie": "NSC_JOfmamujd2zndlkdwlzogneusels0bQ=ffffffff09405a8245525d5f4f58455e445a4a42378b; ROUTEID=.1; JSESSIONID=mu_x-VvVK3_rycxkJ9eef9w7lUPzw-SFLqiyXZnd.r5cvap1013.1dc.com.MP.WEB",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "content-length": 101
}
Body: {"fromDate":"2019-12-19","toDate":"2019-12-19","pageNumber":1,"sortBy":"preAuthDate","sortOrder":"D"}

---

**The response we got was:**

Status: 403 - Forbidden
Headers: {
  "date": "Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:10:19 GMT",
  "server": "Apache",
  "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN, DENY",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15552000; includeSubdomains; preload, max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains",
  "expires": "0",
  "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=3600, must-revalidate",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1",
  "content-security-policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://*.tiqcdn.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/; img-src 'self' data: https://www.google-analytics.com https:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' blob:; font-src 'self' blob:; frame-src 'self' data: *; frame-ancestors 'self'; media-src *;",
  "x-powered-by": "",
  "keep-alive": "timeout=10",
  "connection": "Keep-Alive",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked"
}
Body: {
  "code": "MPERR08",
  "message": "You are not privileged to request this resource.",
  "access-denied": true,
  "cause": "AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE"
}

[Error I Recieved - Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huT40.png)

Comment: Did you made sure that you provide the correct authentication information? Of course a silly question, but just to be sure :-)

Comment: Yes i provided the correct token and JSESSIONID after I logged in. I know this because I made a successful cy.request( get...) call which was dependent on auth token and session. cy.request( ...get...) work fine but cy.request(...post...) fail with 403 Cross Origin, Deny